# Using a loop to create new folders

Tags: loops

I'm new to R and I'm modifying code written by a previous programmer. I'm trying to create a series of reports that are specific to each of our client sites. I'm starting by creating a new folder for each site where all of the site-specific tables and graphs can be placed.

```
site_names <- c("location_name_1", "location_name_2")
    
#Path to save output

BE_tbl_sites_path <- paste0(
  "Z:/Programming and analysis/site reports/site_R_tables", site_names)

for (site in site_names) {
 if (!dir.exists(file.path(BE_tbl_sites_path, site))) {dir.create(file.path(BE_tbl_sites_path))  }
 else {message("Directory already exists for ", site)}
```

When I first ran it, there was an error that "the condition has length > 1". But now when I run it, there's no error but no folders created either. I don't understand why it gave me an error yesterday but not today (I even ran my archived code from yesterday). I tried restarting RStudio, but that didn't make any difference.